Why did my SNES game lose all save data and Game Genie codes overnight?
I purchased a used SNES console, a used game, and a Game Genie. When I turned everything on, it started with no problem.
A day later, after playing it the night before, all of the game's save data was gone, including the Game Genie codes.
What would cause this?

The SNES Game Genie can "save" codes? Are you sure? The NES version didn't had anything like this.

Did the cartridge save battery die? In my experience, they last about 30 years, so it's due.

I wonder since it is a used game if the contacts or anything are damaged. Also, a quick search says that entering certain codes can cause corruption or damage to game data. Is it just a data loss or is the game not functional?

Thank you all for your valued comments.
I realize now that the genie doesn't store codes.
I cleaned the contacts on the game cartridge and on the genie.
I ran the game this morning after it sat turned off for two hours and everything seems to be working.
Again, thank you for your answers.
